# Appending rows in excel xlswriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have created an xls file in which I write some user inputs into the cells. So far so good, the program works; it writes the first line. But when I run again the program instead of  appending the rows it writes on top of the first one. I'm trying to understand how to make it append a new row into the excel sheet save it and close it etc

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx",)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

worksheet.write(row, col,     'odhgos')
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, 'e/p')
worksheet.write(row, col + 2, 'dromologio')
worksheet.write(row, col + 3, 'ora')


row += 1
worksheet.write_string(row, col,     odigosou)
worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, dromou)
worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, dromologio)
worksheet.write_string(row, col + 3, ora)

workbook.close()
```

With this code I created I'm able to write in the file but how do I make it to append a row in the existing sheet. All tutorials I watched, all instructions I researched, just don't work; I'm doing something wrong obviously but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: You can't append to existing file with `xlsxwriter`.

What you can do, is read the file, write it to a new one, and then append on top of that. You could use `openpyxl` which can do this natively, or read the data with something like `xlrd`.

Comment: poo..... i feel really stupid now  thank you very much mate 4 days of work back to 0 again :D dont you love coding ? again thank you very much :)

Comment: If you're running the script above, you're probably getting this Error: `NameError: name 'odigosou' `.  If you quote the 3rd parameter in all your `worksheet.write_string()'s` your script should produce two rows.

Answer (score 13):

> **Question**: ... how do I make it to append a row in the existing sheet

Solution using `openpyxl`, for instance:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

new_row_data = [
    ['odhgos', 'e/p', 'dromologio', 'ora'],
    ['odigosou', 'dromou', 'dromologio', 'ora']]

wb = load_workbook("test/test.xlsx")
# Select First Worksheet
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# Append 2 new Rows - Columns A - D
for row_data in new_row_data:
    # Append Row Values
    ws.append(row_data)

wb.save("test/test.xlsx")
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: workes just fine, also under python 2.7. Cant understand why this response is not marked as solving

Comment: But it appends last rows even I delete rows manually, it does not accept and still adding previous last row like it has'nt been deleted

Comment: @stovfl : have you verified if it works well if the Excel file is formulated ?

Comment: @MustafaUçar You must delete the entire row, not only the contents of the row.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which avoids FileNotFound errors by creating the file if it doesn't exist:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = "myfile.xlsx"
new_row = ['1', '2', '3']

# Confirm file exists. 
# If not, create it, add headers, then append new data
try:
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
except FileNotFoundError:
    headers_row = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(headers_row)

ws.append(new_row)
wb.save(filename)

# Note: if you're adding values from a list, you could instead use:
# new_row = ""
# new_row += [val for val in list]
# Similarly, for adding values from a dict:
# new_row = ""
# new_row = += [val for val in mydict['mykey'].values()]
```